# Vertica SQL query to find Hostnames,CPU and Timestamps for CPU >80 continously for 2 hrs

Tags: sql, database, vertica

Have a DB table in Vertica DB having 3 columns

1. Hostname
2. CPU Util %
3. Timestamp(in Epoch Sec)

1 record will be logged for each Hostname for every 5 mins for CPU Utilization %.
For 1 hour, 12 samples of data will be logged into DB table for each Hostname where each row contains Hostname, CPU Util % and recorded time stamp.

Need an SQL Query for below requirement.
Between any given Start Date Time and End Date Time, Need records where CPU Utilization % exceeds 80 Percent continuously for 2 or more hours ie; CPU Util % is >=80% continuously for more than >=24 samples

Thanks in advance

I tried with subqueries with group by and joining the subquery results. But no results yet.

Comment: Saying that you tried something but it didn't work isn't helpful towards answering. Even if something has failed you should include this with your question. Additionally there is a set of best practices for asking questions. See  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e.g. [look at this working example of your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/jP5b7IpY)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you have any **specific** question about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to calculate the number of continuous samples where CPU utilization % is greater than or equal to 80% for each hostname. To do this the SUM() window function, with CASE expression, counts the number of samples where CPU utilization % is greater than or equal to 80% for each row and the 23 preceding rows (i.e. a total of 24 rows).

The outer query filters the results to only include rows where that calculated number of continuous samples is greater than or equal to 24 (corresponding to 2 or more hours of continuous CPU utilization % greater than or equal to 80%).

Replace `:from_date_time` and `:to_date_time` with the wanted from/to values.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
          hostname
        , cpu_util
        , TIMESTAMP
        , SUM(CASE WHEN cpu_util >= 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (
            PARTITION BY hostname ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ROWS BETWEEN 23 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            ) AS continuous_samples
    FROM cpu_util_table
    WHERE TIMESTAMP >= :from_date_time AND TIMESTAMP < :to_date_time 
    ) AS subquery
WHERE continuous_samples >= 24;
```

[Working example (using SQL Server)](https://dbfiddle.uk/jP5b7IpY)

Comment: Most useful solution